# The meaning of "end-up" in "make sure to place them with the pointed end-up between 3- to 9-inches deep"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following statement talks about how and when to plant bulbs in the fall. I am not sure if "end-up" means something like "the pointed end of the bulb should be planted up", even though I know it refers to a part of the bulb. Thank you!

"[When positioning the bulbs in the soil, make sure to place them with the pointed end-up between 3- to 9-inches deep, depending on the type of bulb.](https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/ideas-how-to/outdoors/lawn-garden/how-and-when-to-plant-bulbs.html?eid=EM_20221007_EN_GC_SPC_WK36_PlantFallBulbs_STC_NA*_PRIM_O_DIY_NA&em=&ET_MID=63155413&ET_RID=65847003)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hyphen shouldn't be there.  It should be "... with the pointed end up"

A bulb has two ends.  One end is rounded or flat, and the other end is pointed.  The bulb should be placed so the pointed end is at the top.